# Unable to create new tag wiki

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

I saw that there was no tag wiki summary for [legend-of-grimrock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-grimrock) yet, so I was going to add it. However, I don't seem to be able to get to the screen that lets me submit an edit.

When I click on the [help us create it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/4394) link, I get taken to the tag's info page, with no link anywhere on there to suggest an edit. I know I've submitted tag wiki summaries in the past... has there been a reputation change or some other bug preventing me from doing it now?

Update: It looks as if I can improve existing tag wikis. I just can't create brand new ones.

Comment: I can reproduce this as well, I wasn't able to add a tag wiki.

Comment: @BenBrocka [It's happening everywhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129002/new-tag-wikis-cannot-be-created).

Comment: Oh, I was editing not creating. Yeah it looks totally borked. [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/data-mining/info) has a pretty create tag wiki button but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for this is being deployed right now.

See [this post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129002/new-tag-wikis-cannot-be-created).